# Update specific column values based upon group by from different column in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have below pandas data frame in python.

[image]

Looking for below output:

[image]

Based upon group of last column I need to pick and repeat first value from and in middle column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
df['col1'] = df['col1'].mask(df['col2'].duplicated()).ffill()
```

Or:

```
df['col1'] = df.groupby('col2')['col1'].transform('first')
```